# Repeat jQuery animation (after left to right)

Tags: jquery, repeat

I already searched for solutions here, but unfortunately nothing worked for me.

I have some animated clouds, that fly from the left to the right of my page, but how could I repeat this animation?

My codes:

(JS)

```
$(window).load(function animation() {   
  $(".big_cloud").delay(5000).animate( { marginLeft: '100%' }, speed, 'linear');
  });
```

(CSS)

```
.big_cloud {
background-image: url('images/big_cloud.png');
width: 272px;
height: 174px;
cursor:pointer;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -280px;
z-index: 3;
}
```

(HTML)

```
<div class="big_cloud"></div>
```

Is it possible to start a repeat, after the cloud is in the middle of the page for example?

Thanks!

Comment: you say you want to "repeat" when the cloud is in the middle, do you mean you want the cloud to go back to the beginning of the page?, or do you mean you want to clone it and add in another cloud? Or do you mean, repeat the animation from the new starting position so it keeps moving across?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it should be "cloned", is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does something like this achieve what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/uxyFE/

I simply move the existing cloud to have the negative margin once the animation has completed and call the function again. Of course this means there is just 1 cloud at a time

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it, maybe I can archieve a good looking sky with some delays, so that there are clouds at everytime

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(".big_cloud").everyTime((speed * 2), function (){
    $(".big_cloud").animate({ marginLeft:'100%' }, speed, 'linear').animate({ marginLeft:'0%' }, speed, 'linear');
});
```

Source: http://www.irengba.com/codewell/